# Bash script: test command -o option

Tags: bash, scripting, test

I have a piece of code like this:

```
count=0
until [ -f $filename -o $count -ge 60 ]
do
  count=$((count+1))
  sleep 1
done
```

I know `[ -f $filename -o $count -ge 60 ]` is a test command, "-f $filename" tests if the file exists or not, "$count -ge 60" tests if count is greater than or equal to 60, what does "-o" mean?

I googled, can't find the answer, anyone can help?

Comment: Try the `help` command for builtins: `help test` (`help [` will tell you it's actually `test`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's logical `OR` operator.

From [bash documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html):

```
expr1 -o expr2
    True if either expr1 or expr2 is true.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a logical or operation. The code checks if `$filename` exists once/second for 60 seconds.